# How do I get data from several files in one histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, data-analysis

For a data analysis, I display the data from the individual folders in individual histograms. In order to get a better overview of the scatter of the measured values, I would now like to display all the data from the folders in a single histogram. Unfortunately, this is simply beyond my technical capabilities. The problem is that this code was not written by me, but was sent to me by one of my colleagues. I have modified it a little so that it fits my problem, but unfortunately my Python knowledge is not yet sufficient for much more.

So here is the code so far:

```
# import libaries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import ptu_reader_JHU as ptu
import csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from glob import glob

# read all .ptu files in folder
files = glob("P:/schlaefke/WRS_Test/New_Data/Multirange_Grid_smallest_Area4/*.ptu")
for file in files:
    
    # create Array with the timestamps of all markers
    header, markertime = ptu.ptu_markertime(file)

    # create array with the distances of the markers
    markertimeshift=np.empty_like(markertime)
    markertimeshift[:1]=0
    markertimeshift[1:]=markertime[:-1]
    markerdistance=np.subtract(markertime, markertimeshift)

    # convert markerdistance into seconds
    markerdistance = markerdistance*header['MeasDesc_GlobalResolution']

    # remove the first marker (sometimes its very fast)
    markerdist_removed=markerdistance[1:]

    # create arrays with long and short distances
    markerdist_group1=markerdist_removed[::2]
    markerdist_group2=markerdist_removed[1::2]

    # calculate variance of the line length
    if max(markerdist_group1)>max(markerdist_group2):
            average = np.average(markerdist_group1)
            variance = np.var(markerdist_group1)
            relvariance = variance/average
            outlier = max((average-min(markerdist_group1), max(markerdist_group1)-average))
            reloutlier = outlier/average
        
    else:
            average = np.average(markerdist_group2)
            variance = np.var(markerdist_group2)
            relvariance = variance/average
            outlier = max((average-min(markerdist_group2), max(markerdist_group2)-average))
            reloutlier = outlier/average

    # find average of long distance
    average_line=max((np.average(markerdist_group1), np.average(markerdist_group2)))

    # determine the number of bins. its 10% of the larger distance (10% of the maximum duration of one line)
    binwidth = average_line/10

    binnr = np.floor((max(markerdistance)-min(markerdistance))/binwidth)

    # create and save plots

    for i in files:
        plt.hist(markerdistance, bins=int(binnr))
        plt.xlabel('Time of markers (s)')
        plt.ylabel('Number of markers')
    plt.show()

     # export data in csv file
    with open("P:\schlaefke\WRS_Test\PTU_Data.csv", "a", newline = "") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([variance, relvariance, outlier, reloutlier])
```

I also tried to use seaborn, but it doesn't work either. I think I try to call the wrong variables:

```
import seaborn as sns

data_histogramm = pd.DataFrame(markerdistance, bins=int(binnr))
sns.histplot(data_histogramm, x="Time of markers (s)", y= "Number of markers")
```

I would be very grateful for any help or tips :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few issues in your code.

**Here's the corrected code:**

```
# import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ptu_reader_JHU as ptu
import csv
from glob import glob
import seaborn as sns

# read all .ptu files in folder
files = glob("P:/schlaefke/WRS_Test/New_Data/Multirange_Grid_smallest_Area4/*.ptu")

# create empty list to store all marker distances
all_marker_distances = []

for file in files:
    # ... (your existing code to process each file)

    # append marker distances to the list
    all_marker_distances.extend(markerdistance)

# determine the number of bins for the combined data
binwidth = average_line / 10
binnr = int(np.floor((max(all_marker_distances) - min(all_marker_distances)) / binwidth))

# create and save the plot
plt.hist(all_marker_distances, bins=binnr)
plt.xlabel('Time of markers (s)')
plt.ylabel('Number of markers')
plt.show()

# export data to a CSV file
with open("P:/schlaefke/WRS_Test/PTU_Data.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([variance, relvariance, outlier, reloutlier])
```

**Now create a DataFrame for Seaborn**

```
data_histogram = pd.DataFrame({'Time of markers (s)': all_marker_distances})
```

**And plot histogram using Seaborn**

```
sns.histplot(data_histogram, x="Time of markers (s)", bins=binnr)
plt.show()
```

Make sure to adapt the Seaborn part according to your needs, as Seaborn might have additional parameters you want to use for customization.

Comment: thx a lot so far! So it is correct, that determine the number and the whole rest of the code isn't in the for loop anymore?